# C# - Populating a List with data from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, viewstate

I have a List (listOfQuestionIDs) stored in ViewState of 10 different numbers and an int counter (questionCounter) stored in ViewState which I intend to use to access the different numbers in the first list.

However, as I increment the value of ViewState["questionCounter"] by 1 the contents of listOfAnswerIDs and listOfAnswers remain exactly the same in the code below. Why is this?

```
protected void getAnswers()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
    MySqlDataReader reader;

    List<int> listOfQuestionIDs = (List<int>)(ViewState["listOfQuestionIDs"]);
    int questionCounter = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["questionCounter"]);

    List<string> listOfAnswerIDs = new List<string>();
    List<string> listOfAnswers = new List<string>();
    List<string> listOfCorrectAnswerIDs = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id=@QuestionID";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuestionID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        cmd.Parameters["@QuestionID"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(listOfQuestionIDs[questionCounter]);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            listOfAnswerIDs.Add(reader["answer_id"].ToString());
            listOfAnswers.Add(reader["answer"].ToString());

            if (reader["correct"].ToString().Equals("Y"))
            {
                listOfCorrectAnswerIDs.Add(reader["answer_id"].ToString());
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfAnswerIDs.Count; i++)
        {
            lblTitle.Text += listOfAnswerIDs[i].ToString();
        }

        reader.Close();

        populateAnswers(listOfAnswerIDs.Count, listOfAnswers, listOfAnswerIDs);
    }
    catch
    {
        lblError.Text = "Database connection error - failed to read records.";
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    ViewState["listOfQuestionIDs"] = listOfQuestionIDs;
    ViewState["listOfCorrectAnswerIDs"] = listOfCorrectAnswerIDs;
}
```

Here's where I increment the questionCounter:

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .........
    getNextQuestion();
}

protected void getNextQuestion()
{
    int questionCounter = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["QuestionCounter"]);
    ..........
    getAnswers();
    ................
    questionCounter += 1;
    ViewState["QuestionCounter"] = questionCounter;
}
```

Comment: Where are you incrementing `ViewState["questionCounter"]` or `questionCounter`?

Comment: Should never have something like this `string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id=@QuestionID";` use stored procedures. Where is this function called

Comment: @BubbleHearth In another function that I've added in the original post.

Comment: @Bhav - how many items do you get in your ViewState?  Just 1?  or do you get 10?

Comment: Have you confirmed that listOfQuestionIDs actually contains a distinct list of question IDs?  you code looks like it *should* work, albeit you really should be disposing some of those objects

Comment: Yes, thanks all. As Becuzz pointed out below, my naming of the keys was inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewState keys are case sensitive.  In getAnswers() you use "questionCounter" and in getNextQuestion() you use "QuestionCounter".  Pick one and keep it consistent.

Comment: It can be handy to keep come `const string` values around to use, to help prevent these kinds of errors.